# Storing multiple images per each entity object in Django with SQLite

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I am currently building myself a website that I could store info of recently release hardware parts (e.g. Motherboard, CPU, etc.)

I am super newb on Web Development and here is my code snippet of current database model.

```py
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)

class Hardware(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    release_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

So, this way I could have stored zero or one image per each entity, but ain't sure how I could make it to  store 0 to more images per each.

It seems like PostgreSQL does support an ArrayField, but since I am using SQLite, I can't really think of the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have several images stored against a single MultiImage object, the best way to do this is to create a separate image model (where you will store all of the images) and then point them back to the MultiImage instance with a foreign key. It will look something like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # add in anything else you want here 
    image = models.ImageField((upload_to='media/')
    multiImage = models.ForeignKey(Hardware, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='other_images')
```

This will mean, each image you create 'points' to a MultiImage instance. The related_name property is how you get all of the images you need. For example:

```
multi_image_instance = Hardware.objects.get(id=...) # or get_object_or_404(Hardware, id=...)
images = multi_image_instance.other_images.all() # this will return a QuerySet
```

In the detail view you can do something like to get all images in template:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src={{ image.image.url }} />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems not possible to install Foreign Keys to abstract models and since my Hardware model is an abstract model, I cannot use this solution :/